# Trying to display terms from custom taxonomy within function

Tags: php, taxonomy, errors, terms

I have a function that is giving me this error - `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in.... blah blah`

Below is some of the code from the function. It is the last line that is giving the error but I can't work out why.
I'm trying to display the term with ID 7 in the project_cats taxonomy.

```
$html_content .= "<h3>" . rgpost('input_1') . "</h3>"; //Title
$html_content .= "<p><strong>Category:</strong> " . rgpost('input_5') . " | <strong>Budget:</strong> " . rgpost('input_3') . "</p>"; //Category & Budget
$html_content .= "<p>" . rgpost('input_4') . "</p>"; //Description
$html_content .= "" . get_term_by('id', 17, 'project_cats') . "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `get_term_by` returns object or array (based on `$output` arg) on success and false if failed. But you treat it as string and try to concatenate it. So your code should be following:

```
$cat = get_term_by('id', 17, 'project_cats');

$html_content .= "<h3>" . rgpost('input_1') . "</h3>"; //Title
$html_content .= "<p><strong>Category:</strong> " . rgpost('input_5') . " | <strong>Budget:</strong> " . rgpost('input_3') . "</p>"; //Category & Budget
$html_content .= "<p>" . rgpost('input_4') . "</p>"; //Description
$html_content .= $cat->name;
```

Read more about this function in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).